# Non greedy dotall regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, search, non-greedy

I need to parse annotations of methods written in PHP. I wrote a regex (see simplified example below) to search them but it doesn't work as expected. Instead of matching the shortest part of text between `/**` and `*/`, it matches the maximum amount of source code (previous methods with annotations). I'm sure I'm using the correct `.*?` non greedy version of `*` and I have found no evidence DOTALL turns it off. Where could be the problem, please? Thank you.

```
p = re.compile(r'(?:/\*\*.*?\*/)\n\s*public', re.DOTALL)
methods = p.findall(text)
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Does removing `re.DOTALL` make it suddenly work again?

Comment: Could you [include some sample data for `text` in a triple-quoted string](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can copy-paste the example into an interpreter session and see the problem for ourselves? (Make sure the sample data displays the problem if *you* copy-paste the example into an interpreter session.)

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: No, without `re.DOTALL` it won't work at all - nothing found.

Comment: `\s` matches `\n` character aslo.

Comment: `text = """
/**
 * comment
 */
class MyClass extens Base
{
    /**
     * comment
     */
    public function xyz """`

Comment: @user3853423: Put it in the code in the question.

Comment: seems like your second `/* *` contains a space.

Comment: I assume .*? can match space too, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex engines parse from left to right. A lazy quantifier will attempt to match the least it can from the current match position, but it can't push the match start forward, even if that would reduce the amount of text matched. That means rather than starting at the last `/**` before the `public`, it's going to match from the first `/**` to the next `*/` that's attached to a `public`.

If you want to exclude `*/` from inside the comment, you'll need to group the `.` with a lookahead assertion:

```
(?:(?!\*/).)
```

The `(?!\*/)` asserts that the character we're matching is not the start of a `*/` sequence.

Comment: It should look like this? `p = re.compile(r'(?:/\*\*(?!\*/).*?\*/)\n\s*public', re.DOTALL)
`

Comment: @user3853423: Yeah, I just realized I forgot to mention that the assertion has to be grouped with the `.`, so the `*?` runs the assertion each time. It should look like `r'(?:/\*\*(?:(?!\*/).)*?\*/)\n\s*public'`. Incidentally, this regex is messy enough that using [verbose mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X) would probably be a good idea.

Comment: I'm using `r'(?:/\*\*(?:(?!\*/).)*?\*/)\s*public'` now but I found out that I won't found methods without annotations (second comment omitted in the example input) in spite there is ?: at the beginning of the regexp. What's wrong, please?

Comment: @user3853423: I thought that was what you wanted. `?:` doesn't mean optional; it means non-capturing. If you want to make it optional, put a `?` after the group.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to get this,

```
>>> text = """ /** * comment */ class MyClass extens Base { /** * comment */ public function xyz """
>>> m = re.findall(r'\/\*\*(?:(?!\*\/).)*\*\/\s*public', text, re.DOTALL)
>>> m
['/** * comment */ public']
```

If you don't want `public` in the final match then use the below regex which uses positive lookahead,

```
>>> m = re.findall(r'\/\*\*(?:(?!\*\/).)*\*\/(?=\s*public)', text, re.DOTALL)
>>> m
['/** * comment */']
```

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse you. When no annotation is present before `public` the `public function xyz` text must me found because I also parse method header.

Comment: please post the actual input in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness, user3853423 has already answered my question.

Comment: I think he just explained my regex that's all

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this:

```
\/\*\*([^*]|\*[^/])*?\*\/\s*public
```

That will match any symbol that isn't an asterix (*), and if is an asterix it's not allowed to be followed by a forward slash. Meaning it should only capture comments that are closed just before public and not sooner.

Example: http://regexr.com/398b3

Explanation: http://tinyurl.com/lcewdmo

**Disclaimer:** If the comment contains `*/` inside it, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Some examples and assuming that the annotation you want to parse
# starts with a /** and ends with a */.  This may be spread over
# several lines.

text = """
/**
 @Title(value='Welcome', lang='en')
 @Title(value='Wilkommen', lang='de')
 @Title(value='Vitajte', lang='sk')
 @Snippet
    ,*/
class WelcomeScreen {}

   /** @Target("method") */
  class Route extends Annotation {}

/** @Mapping(inheritance = @SingleTableInheritance,
    columns = {@ColumnMapping('id'), @ColumnMapping('name')}) */
public Person {}

"""

text2 = """ /** * comment */
CLASS MyClass extens Base {

/** * comment */
public function xyz
"""


import re

# Match a PHP annotation and the word following class or public
# function.
annotations = re.findall(r"""/\*\*             # Starting annotation
                                               # 
                            (?P<annote>.*?)    # Namned, non-greedy match
                                               # including newline
                                               #
                             \*/               # Ending annotation
                                               #
                             (?:.*?)           # Non-capturing non-greedy
                                               # including newline
                 (?:public[ ]+function|class)  # Match either
                                               # of these
                             [ ]+              # One or more spaces
                             (?P<name>\w+)     # Match a word
                         """,
                         text + text2,
                         re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)

for txt in annotations:
     print("Annotation: "," ".join(txt[0].split()))
     print("Name: ", txt[1])
```